# Conditionally register collection in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I would like to conditionally register types to a collection based on who the Consumer is. Something like:

```cs
Container.Collection.RegisterConditionally(
    typeof(IEventHandler<>),
    myPublisherTypes, 
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(PublishEventDecorator<,>));

Container.Collection.RegisterConditionally(
    typeof(IEventHandler<>),
    myTypes, 
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType != typeof(PublishEventDecorator<,>));
```

The scenario is that I want some types of `IEventHandler<>` to be resolved in the constructor of `PublishEventDecorator` as an collection; `IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>`. And the rest be resolved anywhere else they are requested.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should

Comment: *I want some types of IEventHandler<> to be resolved* the use of a generic here, seems problematic. I think we're going to need to see concrete examples of exactly what you want to do. This looks like it breaks [LSP](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/)

Comment: I don't agree that this breaks the LSP, or at least, the LSP could be broken, but the currently posted code doesn't clearly shows the LSP to be broken. but I do like to see a more concrete example of what it is you are trying to achieve, because there might be more elegant solutions that don't require complex configurations in S.I.

Answer (score 2):

Although Simple Injector contains several features that would allow you to register collections conditionally, it lacks any out-of-the-box feature that would allow you to do this on collections of *open-generic abstractions*.

But there are ways around this. For instance, you can inject a list of `InstanceProducer` instances into the decorator. This would result in a registration such as the following:

```cs
Container.Register(typeof(IPublishEvent<>), typeof(PublishEvent<>));
Container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IPublishEvent<>), typeof(PublishEventDecorator<>));
Container.Collection.Register(typeof(IEventHandler<>), myTypes);

// Create a list of InstanceProducer instances for the list of publisher types.
// InstanceProducers are Simple Injector's registration factories. They are used
// to resolve instances from the container.
InstanceProducer[] myPublisherTypesProducers = (
    from implementation in myPublisherTypes
    from service in implementation.GetClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>))
    select Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer(service, implementation, Container))
    .ToArray();

// This conditional registration injects the instance producers into the decorator.
Container.RegisterConditional<InstanceProducer[]>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
        typeof(InstanceProducer[]), myPublisherTypesProducers, Container),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType
        .GetClosedTypesOf(typeof(PublishEventDecorator<>)).Any());
```

The consequence of this registration is that you need to specially craft your decorator, since it needs to depend on the list of `InstanceProducer` instances. With it, it starts to depend on Simple Injector. Because of this, it's good practice to move the decorator into your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Here's its possible implementation:

```cs
public class PublishEventDecorator<T> : IPublishEvent<T>
{
    private readonly IPublishEvent<T> decoratee;
    private readonly InstanceProducer[] handlerProducers;

    public PublishEventDecorator(
        IPublishEvent<T> decoratee, InstanceProducer[] handlerProducers)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.handlerProducers = handlerProducers;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IEventHandler<T>> Handlers =>
        from producer in this.handlerProducers
        where producer.ServiceType == typeof(IEventHandler<T>)
        select (IEventHandler<T>)producer.GetInstance();

    public void Publish(T @event)
    {
        // Do something with handlers
        foreach (var handler in this.Handlers) { }

        // Invoke decoratee.
        this.decoratee.Publish(@event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I decided to take a different approach than I initially thought. Since my design became a bit hard to understand :)